# LLDP messages forwarding

Tags: switch, lldp

Should LLDP messages be forwarded through simple switch (one that does not support 802.1d)? I have two switches: D-link DGS-1008D and TP-link TL-SF1008D and the first one forwards them and the second one seems to forward some of them (but not others). Messages are sent to 01-80-C2-00-00-0E MAC address.